# Making the conditional operators behave like if/else statements in C

Tags: c, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

Is it possible to make the `?:` operator process several statements like in the example below?

```
condition ? FirstTrueExpression SecondTrueExpression : FirstFalseExpression SecondFalseExpression
```

And is there a way to avoid specifying the 'else' statement?

```
condition ? TrueExpression
```

Comment: The headline does not match well but I do not have a clue how to name it

Comment: @alvits Nope. This is not allowed: `while({x<10})`

Comment: Question: "I have a screwdriver.  How can I use it as jack to change a tire on my car?"  Answer:  "You **DON'T**.  You use a jack."  The proper tool to use in this case is an `if` statement, with or without an `else` as needed.  Using the `?:` operator here would at best result in hard-to-understand, unmaintainable, and bug-prone code.  Or, in the case where you want to omit the `:` portion of the operator, a syntax error.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The question is not about "How should I write my code", it is about the functionality of the whole language, but thanks for your answer anyway

Comment: `?:` doesn't process statements at all, so no, you cannot make it process 0, 1, 2 or more statements. Operands of `?:` are expressions, not statements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use comma operator `,` to concatenate multiple expressions.
The expressions are evaluated from left to right and its resulting type and value will be ones of the righthand expression.

```
condition ? FirstTrueExpression, SecondTrueExpression : (FirstFalseExpression, SecondFalseExpression)
```

Note that you need `()` around `(FirstFalseExpression, SecondFalseExpression)` due to the operator precedence while you don't need `()` around `FirstTrueExpression, SecondTrueExpression`.

You can use

```
condition && TrueExpression
```

instead of

```
condition ? TrueExpression
```

This is thanks to *short-circuit evaluation* of logical and `&&` operator:
When `condition` is false, `condition && TrueExpression` will be false (`0`) regardless of the value of `TrueExpression`, and therefore `TrueExpression` isn't evaluated.
When `condition` is true, `TrueExpression` is evaluated because it is needed to determine the value of `condition && TrueExpression`.

Comment: I didn't quite get the issue about the precedence and why there should be brackets around the last body

Comment: `?:` has higher precedence than `,`, so `A ? B : C, D` is interpreted as `(A ? B : C), D`, not `A ? B : (C, D)` and `D` will be evaluated unconditionally. [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AadvmK9dDtDvFIeT)

Comment: @MikeCAT - the operator is `?:` - there is no `?` operator, and that is why `condition ? TrueExpression` is unlikely to compile correctly.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica is there something in C like `pass` in Python to put it after the colon?

Comment: @Kaiyaha You may like `condition && TrueExpression` instead of `condition ? TrueExpression`.

Comment: @MikeCAT - you should add that in your answer.

Comment: @MikeCAT yes please add that to your answer. Maybe you have an idea for a better headline for the question, do you?